# Android and XML Usage

Tags: android

Hai,

I am developing a Puzzle in Android.
The puzzle is something like finding a number.
It contains 7 steps.
Here I use 7 xml files
Each file is meant for some operations
The 7th file displays the output.
There is a Try again button in the 7th file and when the user clicks on that button, it should  call the 1st xml file and repeat the same process again.
The code for that navigation is something like:
setcontentView(R.layout.main1); where main1 is the 1st xml file.

The problem is that, the control goes to the 1st file but the processes can't be repeated.ie. the controls inside that page will be in inactive state.

Can any one give some suggestions here?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to raise the initial `Intent` on the Try Again button press.  This should reinitialise the application, and should have the added benefit of allowing the user to go `Back` to their previous result.

These are only ideas though, I'm a noob at Android development....